# approximating $\frac{S^2}{\sigma^2}$

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ be independent random variables from a normal distribution with expected value $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and let $S^2 = \dfrac{1}{n-1} \sum^n_{i=1} (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$ be the sample variance. use the Central limit theorem to show that the distribution of $\dfrac{S^2}{\sigma^2}$ can be approximated by a normal distribution with expectation 1 and variance $\frac{2}{n-1}$. for a lrage value of $n$, suggest a distribution that can be used to approximate the distribution of $S^2$.

Now I have tried this exercise but the explanation that our teacher gave us was just nonexistent. My try was writing out $\frac{S^2}{\sigma^2}$ but that yielded something was unwieldy, my second try was using $\frac{\frac{1}{(n-1)}S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2(\frac{1}{n-1})$ (out of despair) but that doesnt really work beacuse $\mu$ would be $\frac{1}{n-1}$ but the bright side: the $\sigma^2$ would be $\frac{2}{n-1}$ (yes I know this isnt even possible as it should be $n-1$ and not $\frac{1}{n-1}$.)

Any help whatsoever? The answer was just : look at slides (which of course I did)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, and for others that may stumble upon this:

we have $Z =\frac{Y_i -\bar{Y}}{\sigma}$ and $Z^2 \sim \chi^2(1) = V$

$$
\dfrac{\sum^{n-1}_i Z^2}{n-1}  = \bar{V}
$$
now we can do some nice tricks:
$$
\begin{align}
E[\bar{V}] &= E\left[\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}V_i\right] = \frac{n-1}{n-1}E[V]=1 \\
\operatorname{Var}(\bar{V})&=\frac{n-1}{(n-1)^2}\operatorname{Var}(V) = \frac{2}{n-1}
\end{align}
$$

I don't know how if I am allowed to answer my own question. Im glad I finally understand it.

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to answer your own question.